# Haskell stack version dependencies

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

New to Stack.  I'm starting to build a [concurrent web scraper](http://adit.io/posts/2012-03-10-building_a_concurrent_web_scraper_with_haskell.html), and ran `stack new my-project simple`.  In `my-project.cabal` I have to insert the dependencies for hxt, url, http, and maybet.

```
executable my-project
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       time,
                       hxt,
                       http,
                       maybet
```

When I run `stack build`, I get this:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for my-project-0.1.0.0:
    http must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version
    maybet must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version
needed since my-project is a build target.

Some potential ways to resolve this:

  * Set 'allow-newer: true' to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.

  * You may also want to try using the 'stack solver' command.
```

Inserting `allow-newer: true` under the executable directive doesn't seem to work and adding version suffixes like `http == *` gives a parse error, and giving it `http == 4000.3.9,` as per the [hackage docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP) gives me     `http must match ==4000.3.9, but the stack configuration has no specified version`

Is there an easy way to tell the cabal file that I want the newest version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no package named `http` in Hackage. But you have a package named `HTTP`.

So, fixing the package name should resolve the problem for you.

(Also the blog article seems quite outdated, the standard way of doing HTTP request is via conduit/wreq/req these days).